# Communication between multiple Azure Mobile Apps? Via HttpClient or different options? (.Net-Backend)

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-sdk-.net

Simplified scenario:

One Azure Mobile App "ServiceManagement" in eu (including database)

Two Azure Mobile Apps, same code, one in EU "ServiceEU", one in US "ServiceUS" (each with their own seperate database)

Customer signs in to ServiceManagement, selects what region he wants his data to be hosted at. Customer buys service options -> payment record, selected options etc. are saved in ServiceManagement.

Now ServiceManagement connects to either ServiceEU or ServiceUS and and tells it to create the corresponding service plan for the customer. Beyond the times the customer buys service options there will be no communication between the services.

**Are there any other options besides `HttpClient` to handle the communication between the Azure Mobile App "ServiceManagement" and "ServiceEU" or "ServiceUS"?**

My current code seems to work but I couldn't find any resources/documentation for cases like this. So I'm not sure if there are better alternatives.

```
/// <summary>
/// Hosted in ServiceManagement
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("completeRemote")]
[ResponseType(typeof(String))]
public async Task<string> completeRemote()
{

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ZUMO-API-VERSION", "2.0.0");

    //Calling completeAll from different Azure Mobile App "<url>"
    var res = await client.GetAsync("https://<url>/api/Test/completeAll");
    res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var str = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    str = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<String>(str);

    //verify request completed
    //Do something with str

    return str;
}
```

Please keep in mind that this is a very simplified concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any other options besides HttpClient to handle the communication between the Azure Mobile App "ServiceManagement" and "ServiceEU" or "ServiceUS"?

As far as I know, the C# mobile app backend is a web api. Normally we will use httpclient to send the request to the web api application to get the result.

If you don't want to use the httpclient, you could use azure mobile client SDK.

It is easily to write codes.

You could install it from the Nuget Package.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client
```

Here is the sample code, hope it gives you some tips:

Notice: It still will send the request to the mobile app backend.

```
    public static async Task<string> GetApplicationToken()
    {
        var clientUri = $"https://your-mobile-app-id.azurewebsites.net";

        var client = new MobileServiceClient(clientUri);
        var response = await client.InvokeApiAsync<string>("/api/values", HttpMethod.Get, null);
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried this first. An exception is thrown when initializing `MobileServiceClient`. It would be the preferred method to `HttpClient` since I'm using MobileServiceClient in all apps connecting to the services. I'll check again

Comment: Update: Looked into it again and solved the problem. When using `MobileServiceClient` in the backend service, it uses the wrong API version. I managed to get it working by adding the "ZUMO-API-VERSION" parameter with "2.0.0" value: `Dictionary<String, String> d = new Dictionary<string, string>(); d.Add("ZUMO-API-VERSION", "2.0.0");
                str = await client.InvokeApiAsync<String>("Test/completeAll", HttpMethod.Get, d);`

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of Azure Service Bus (or host your own service bus)

> Depend on Azure Service Bus when you need highly reliable cloud
>   messaging service between applications and services, even when one or
>   more is offline.

about Enterprise service bus on wikipedia:

> An enterprise service bus (ESB) implements a communication system
>   between mutually interacting software applications in a
>   service-oriented architecture (SOA).
>
> ...
>
> As it implements a software architecture for distributed computing, it
>   therefore also implements a special variant of the more general
>   client-server model. Whereas in general any application using ESB can
>   behave as server or client in turns.